# Flutter change the child icon color of FloatingActionButton

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm new to **Flutter** and was trying to change the child icon color of FloatingActionButton. Child icon color is white by default.

How can i change that??

Given below is the code that i have worked on.

```
floatingActionButton: new FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: new Icon(Icons.add),
        backgroundColor: Colors.yellow,

      ), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
    );
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can wrap in an `IconTheme`

```
child: new IconTheme(
    data: new IconThemeData(
        color: Colors.yellow), 
    child: new Icon(Icons.add),
),
```

or a `Theme` where `iconTheme` is set the way you want it

(not tested)

Answer (score 19):

To change the color of child Icon, You have to set the color in the Icon() widget.

Here I am sharing the code snippet where I have set the red color.

```
floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: new Icon(Icons.add, color: Colors.red,),
        backgroundColor: Colors.yellow,
      ),
```

Comment: Thanks mahn, it worked. Accepting Günter Zöchbauer 's answer as he answered first.

Comment: No Problem at ll :)

Comment: chal be @DhrumilShah-dhuma1981

Answer (score 5):

**Flutter v17.4**

This worked for me, if you just want to change to colour of icon.

```
floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
    child: Icon(Icons.add,
      color: Colors.black, //The color which you want set.
    ),
    onPressed: () => {},
  ),
```

Answer (score 1):

## MaterialApp theme: ThemeData

If using `ThemeData` in your `MaterialApp` to color your app like:

```
    return MaterialApp(
        title: 'Flutter Demo',
        theme: lightThemeData, // this guy
        darkTheme: darkThemeData, // and perhaps this guy
        home: MyHomePage()
    );
```

... you have **2 ways to color your FloatingActionButton (FAB) Icon color in `ThemeData`**:

1. `floatingActionButtonTheme: const FloatingActionButtonThemeData(foregroundColor: myColor)`
2. `onSecondary: myColor` (used *only* if ↑↑↑ is missing)

```
final lightThemeData = ThemeData.from(
    colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(
      seedColor: Colors.blue,
      brightness: Brightness.light,
      primary: blue,
      secondary: blue,
      onSecondary: white, // FAB Icon color if FABTheme not provided like below
    ),
).copyWith(
  floatingActionButtonTheme: const FloatingActionButtonThemeData(foregroundColor: Colors.green), // this guy works
  iconTheme: const IconThemeData(color: white), // DOES NOT affect FAB Icon
  accentIconTheme: const IconThemeData(color: purpleRain), // argumentFormerlyKnownAsFabIconColor - deprecated, DON'T USE THIS
);
```

In the above `themeData` example, the FAB Icon would be colored **green**.

Because `onSecondary` is used to color the FAB icon *only* if `floatingActionButtonTheme` is missing.

If neither of the above theme colors are provided, the FAB Icon will fallback to black color.

`iconTheme` and `accentIconTheme` ***both have no effect*** on FAB icon color.

FAB `accentIconTheme` [change happened in Flutter 1.17](https://docs.flutter.dev/release/breaking-changes/fab-theme-data-accent-properties).