# Color property for FAB icon in Flutter ThemeData

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, material-design, themes

**Question:**

What is the property(?) for changing the default color of the icons in floating action buttons in flutter? I know *accentColor* changes the background color of the FAB. Is there even one or does it have to be declared in the regular code? For example, if I wanted to change the icon color of the FAB pictured below to white or pink or whatever.

[image: flutter]

[image]

[image]

Comment: use `floatingActionButtonTheme: FloatingActionButtonThemeData(foregroundColor: Colors.someColor)` See [more](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72762019/2301224)

Answer (score 1):

You can change the icon color of the FAB by passing Color to the `color` property of Icon.

```
floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
  backgroundColor: Colors.red,
  onPressed: () {},
  child: Icon(Icons.add, color: Colors.white)
  ),
),
```